# verbatim rendering of strings with { } in code chunks of roxygen documentation

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I have some regex expressions that I want to put into my R package documentation:

```
this <- c("letter-number"="^([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]+)")
```

When I put this into the `roxygen` doc strings as

```
#' @details This is the regex schema that I use: "`r this`".
#' @export
this <- c("letter-number"="^([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]+)")
```

it gets rendered as ^([a-zA-Z]10-9+), i.e. the curly brackets are absorbed / the expression inside the curly brackets is evaluated. Looking at the compiled `.Rd` file, I suspect it is the problem of the help file rendering, as in that file, the line shows up as `"^([a-zA-Z]{1}\link{0-9}+)"` (although it is problematic that `roxygen` has converted the square brackets to the `\link{}` instruction; it gets ignored when I view the help file with `?this`).

What is an appropriate way to display this kind of string verbatim?

```
> packageVersion("roxygen2")
[1] ‘7.1.2’
> packageVersion("devtools")
[1] ‘2.4.3’
> packageVersion("glue")
[1] ‘1.6.2’
```

(I am stuck with a dated R 4.1.2 at the moment.)

Comment: I can't reproduce this, though it is a problem. For the above, I get `"^([a-zA-Z]{1}\link{0-9}+)"`, where `link` is wrong.

Comment: This appears to be `glue`-induced? My guess is that the inline R-expression `\`r this\`` is processed _before_ follow-on markdown rendering. (The use of `@noMd` does not work, as that disables inline R expression evaluation completely.)

Comment: @r2evans thanks for looking into this. I have also found `\link{}` in the .Rd file, but altogether it is rendered wrong in RStudio help pane. (Maybe I should go to their community and raise the issue there?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this *might* be a bug in `roxygen2` (or its use of `rmarkdown`), if you can tolerate a helper-function, then we can do this:

```r
backticks <- function(z) paste0('`', z, '`')
#' This.
#' @details This is the regex schema that I use: "`r backticks(this)`".
#' @export
this <- c("letter-number"="^([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]+)")
```

Rendered with `devtools::document()` (among other ways, same-effect) results in this in the `man/this.Rd` file:

```
\details{
This is the regex schema that I use: "\verb{^([a-zA-Z]\{1\}[0-9]+)}".
}
```

which renders as

```
Details:

     This is the regex schema that I use: "^([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]+)".
```

---

For context, R-4.2.3 in emacs/ESS with

```
packageVersion("roxygen2")
# [1] '7.2.3'
packageVersion("devtools")
# [1] '2.4.5'
packageVersion("rmarkdown")
# [1] '2.20'
packageVersion("glue")
# [1] '1.6.2'
```

Comment: rmarkdown doesn't have an escape character? https://github.com/veleek/til/blob/master/markdown/escaping-hash-characters-in-markdown.md

Comment: I was working more on the premise that we don't want to add literal escapes to the underlying vector string, only to how it is rendered, since once the raw string is rendered into the doc, markdown is then processed, which handles some of the string specially. I don't know if the behavior is intentional and I'm subverting something, nor if there is a better approach, but this worked \*shrug\* @IRTFM

Comment: Hm. I can tolerate _a lot_ of crap. But `devtools::check()` is not going to like an undocumented function ;). Thanks!